# Is it possible to use SublimeBlender on a MacOS?

Tags: python, scripting, workflow, add-on, external-applications

I tried installing the blender addon and the sublime 3 package (https://github.com/svenfraeys/SublimeBlender). Installing went all well and I can enable the blender addon to start the connection. But within in Sublime 3 when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> nothing happens.

Any thoughts? Anyone the same problem on a Mac?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should at least try the Issue tracker for https://github.com/svenfraeys/SublimeBlender/issues . The paths are hardcoded "Packages/Blender Development" but the zip is called "SublimeBlender-master" -- that will never, ever, work. -- this should be fixed permanently in the addon not as a quick fix here.

Comment: it looks like [somebody already went through this in their bug tracker on github](https://github.com/svenfraeys/SublimeBlender/issues/2).

Comment: It appears that the shortcut alt + P on a mac creates the π sign. I altered the shortcut to something else and a simple bpy method worked! Have problems right now with running my initial script containg a class within in Blender.